# Updating upload progress on Realm Object

Tags: ios, realm

I'm trying to update a progress property on my Realm object which looks like this:

```
class Upload: Object {

  dynamic var name: String = ""
  dynamic var key: String = ""
  dynamic var localIdentifier:String = ""
  dynamic var data: NSData? = nil
  dynamic var albumKey: String = ""
  dynamic var isUploading: Bool = false
  dynamic var status: String = ""
  dynamic var progress: Float = 0.0
  dynamic var urlString: String = ""
  let isVideo = RealmOptional<Bool>()

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "localIdentifier"
  }
}
```

The framework i'm using give a progress update for the upload every .5 seconds approx. The callback looks like this:

```
task.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
            let float = Float(snapshot.progress!.fractionCompleted)
            self.update(progress: float, forUpload: upload)
        }

fileprivate func update(progress: Float, forUpload upload: Upload) {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            let u = Upload()
            u.progress = progress
            u.localIdentifier = upload.localIdentifier
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(u, update: true)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

With the above code, it keeps crashing and giving me a 'RLMException', reason: 'The Realm is already in a write transaction'.

I dont' know whether this error occurs because I have 3 concurrent downloads running, or because the object in question is busy (I thought that creating a new object assigning it with the same primary key would alleviate this?)

So my question is, how do I go about this? Am I trying to do something that is a bit outside of what you would use realm for?

Comment: What's the rationale for creating a whole new `Upload` object each time `update()` is called? Since you are passing in an existing `Upload` object, I would think it makes more sense to just write the new value of `progress` to the existing `upload`.

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that `task.observe` runs aynchronously in a separate thread, `update` is running on the same thread, so you could get two running at once. The easiest thing to do would be to force running it on the main thread:

```
task.observe(.progress) { snapshot in
            let float = Float(snapshot.progress!.fractionCompleted)
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.update(progress: float, forUpload: upload)
            }
        }
```

I'm also guessing that you're creating a new `Upload` instance each time because otherwise they would be accessed from different threads. If you run on the main thread you could therefore just update the progress on the one instance.

Comment: Dispatching to a background serial queue would have the same effect, without blocking the main thread.